# how to make XTerm never use bold characters?

Tags: colors, fonts, xterm, display-settings

I am trying to make XTerm to never use a bold font, and nothing seems to work. I put settings in `~/.Xresources` and then run `xrdb ~/.Xresources` and then start a new XTerm. This is what I try:

```
XTerm*background: gray90
XTerm*foreground: black
XTerm*highlightColor: yellow
XTerm*pointerColor: red
XTerm*pointerColorBackground: white
XTerm*cursorColor: navy
XTerm*borderColor: black

Xterm*colorBD: black
XTerm*colorBDMode: true

XTerm*boldMode: false
XTerm*alwaysBoldMode: false

XTerm*font:        -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1
XTerm*boldFont:    -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1
XTerm*utf8Fonts.font:        -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1
XTerm*utf8Fonts.boldFont:    -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1
```

And still for example when I run Midnight Commander all directory names are with thick letters, and I want them the same as normal files, just use a color, but not make them thicker! In VIM everything uses thick letters when syntax highlighting is used (but is OK - thin - when there is no syntax highlighting).

I am out of ideas, what to put in my `~/.Xresources` to force XTerm to never use those thick letters?

Answer (score 6):

You should stick this in your `~/.Xresources` file or maybe the deprecated `~/.Xdefaults` file:

```
XTerm*allowBoldFonts:       false
```

You can also press `Ctrl` while right-clicking `xterm` and tick/untick the **Bold Fonts** option.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this (I don't see any bold font when I use your settings, but this may be due to other settings of mine, I haven't looked too closely).

You may be missing a setting of `XTerm*boldColors`.

Note that in `Xterm*colorBD: black`, the class is miscapitalized (you wrote `Xterm` instead of `XTerm`).