# Disable bold font in urxvt

Tags: terminal, configuration, fonts, rxvt

I want to disable the bold font in my urxvt config (`.Xresources`). xterm has the option [allowBoldFonts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31999/how-to-make-xterm-never-use-bold-characters). Is there a similar option for urxvt? I can't find anything similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can effectively disable bold fonts by just applying the same font string for both urxvt's regular and bold fonts in `.Xresources`, for example:

```
URxvt.font:xft:droid sans mono slashed:size=10.5
URxvt.boldFont:xft:droid sans mono slashed:size=10.5
```

Comment: Perfect! :) . Thanks also by the edition of my question.

Answer (score 15):

According to the manual, setting URxvt.boldFont to empty will disable the bold font, and uses regular font instead. This is the preferred way I think.

```
URxvt.boldFont:
```